# Tumblr and Sitemaps

Tags: google-analytics, sitemap, tumblr

I was wondering if anyone knew how to add a sitemap to a tumblr blog.

It was what i use to share stuff online. Since tumblr doesn't let you upload to

> example.com/sitemap

So there lies my problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for or do you need more information?

Comment: @Christopher actually no. but I did find a good article on it here http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/2178282519/top-5-things-to-do-after-launching-a-tumblr-blog

Comment: If you've already found the answer, could you answer your own question and close it out please?

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr actually creates the sitemap for you automatically under the path /sitemap1.xml - its automatically generated from the pages on your tumblr site.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/generate-xml-sitemap-of-tumblr-blog-submit-to-google/) gives Tumblrmap as a good example.

**Edit:** as stated in the comment below this site is now dead.

HOWEVER. It looks like Tumblr now has sitemaps. Go to http://site.tumblr.com/sitemap.xml

On the site I checked (http://kylewritescode.com) it gave a URL to another page. I went to that page and the sitemap is there. However, I'm assuming that on most others the original page is the sitemap.

Comment: this site no longer works.

Comment: I've updated my previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have install the sitemap you will apera here:    http://www.bing.com/webmaster/http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/